# 'init(contentsOfURL:)' is unavailable: APIs deprecated as of iOS 7 and earlier are unavailable in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can't find any alternate method of `contentsOfURL` to resolve this issue.

Here is my Swift code:

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class MapHelper{


func geoCodeUsingAddress(address:String) ->CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    var latitude = 0.0
    var longitude = 0.0
    let esc_addr = address.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let req = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=\(esc_addr)"

    let result:NSString? = NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: req)); // here is error //msg comes

    if let value=result{
        let scanner:NSScanner = NSScanner(string: value)
        if(scanner.scanUpToString("\"lat\" :", intoString: nil) && scanner.scanString("\"lat\" :", intoString: nil)){
            scanner.scanDouble(&latitude)
        }
        if(scanner.scanUpToString("\"lng\" :", intoString: nil) && scanner.scanString("\"lng\" :", intoString: nil)){
            scanner.scanDouble(&longitude);
        }
    }
    else{

    }

    var center:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0);
    center.latitude = latitude;
    center.longitude = longitude;
    return center;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the old contentsWithURL that has since been deprecated. You need to add an encoding and error now.

```
let result = NSString(contentsOfURL: "http://www.google.com", encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let urlPath: String = "YOUR URL HERE"
let data = NSString(contentsOfURL: urlPath, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `contentsOfURL:encoding:` is not recommended when loading from a remote server. You are better off using dedicated methods from `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` suitable for this task.

The simplest approach is to use `NSURLConnection`s class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. This approach has some restrictions, though - for example, it cannot be cancelled and authentication only works with passing the credentials in the URL with HTTB basic authentication.

For further reference, see "Loading Data Asynchronously" in [NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html)

See also: [Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)